# Updating config on runtime for a user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1

I created a function to get smtp info from db for a user `$mail_config=STMPDetails::where('user_id',36)->first()` and then I can just call `config` helper function and pass the array to set config value `config($mail_config)`. and then I call `Mail::queue` function.

but before it reaches `createSmtpDriver@vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php` where it reads the configuration again to send the mail, mail config are changed to the one specified in .env file.

Another thing to note is Mail sending function is in a Listener

I am not able to figure out where can I call the function such that configuration changes are retained before mail is sent.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
// Set your new config
Config::set('mail.driver', $driver);
Config::set('mail.from', ['address' => $address, 'name' => $name]);

// Re execute the MailServiceProvider that should use your new config
(new Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

Comment: Can I do this in the same Listener file where I am calling the `Mail::queue`?

Comment: You know what, you nailed it

Comment: I personally created a helper function that I call every time I need to switch my mailer configuration.

Comment: I did exact same thing that Alejandro updated showed, it wasn't working, but after I added the register() function as you suggested it worked, what is the reason it didn't work without re-registering. BTW I created a helper function too :)

Comment: If my solution worked well, please set my answer as accepted for future viewers :)

Comment: yes your solution worked, please give bit more information why this worked, and why there was no information about doing what you suggested in laravel documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Since the default MailServiceProvider is a [deferred provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#deferred-providers), you should be able to change config details before the service is actually created.

Could you show the contents of `$mail_config`? I'm guessing that's the problem. It should be something like

```
config(['mail.port' => 587]);
```

---

Update - tested in 5.1 app:

```
Mail::queue('emails.hello', $data, function ($mail) use ($address) {
    $mail->to($address);
});
```

->> Sent normally to recipient.

```
config(['mail.driver' => 'log']);

Mail::queue('emails.hello', $data, function ($mail) use ($address) {
    $mail->to($address);
});
```

->> Not sent; message logged.

Comment: If I read the config('mail') immediately after setting the values it is all correct, but by the time config values are used by the Mail/TransportManager it is reset to values from the .env

Comment: @karmendra That's strange. See my updated answer please. Anyway, re-registering the service provider will definitely work (as the other answer suggests).

Comment: I was doing the exact same thing you showed here and it didn't work, and I wasn't able to figure out why.

Comment: Another thing to note is, Mail::queue is called in a Listener, does that have to do anything with it. queue driver is sync anyway. Can you try your code in a Listener?

Comment: @karmendra Yes. Works ok from a listener too